# Merging text from multiple cells into one cell

Tags: vba, excel, merge

I am new to VBA and I am trying to solve a small problem at work.
How can I copy string from **some** cells into **one** merged cell?

lets say I have five cells with string in them:

```
One
Two
Three
Four
Five
```

I need to take them and create a cell with these words **one under the other**

Comment: `1` Store the contents of the cells in a variable `2` Merge the cells `3` cell.value = variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
Sub test()
Dim mergedStr As String
Dim afterFirst As Boolean
For Each cell In Range("A1:A5")
    If afterFirst Then mergedStr = mergedStr & Chr(10)
    mergedStr = mergedStr & cell.Value
    afterFirst = True
Next cell
Range("d3").Value = mergedStr
End Sub
```

Comment: It wont write the last string and start with a blank.

Comment: The last string is actually there, it's just further down which is a problem if your merged cell is the exact amount of rows required. I've edited it now so sorry about that.